# How to run a mysql script file using a mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql

I want to run several .sql files in a defined order. So I thought to write a stored procedure which is called for each file in another .sql file.I can't find an example of such a mysql procedure.If you can please help me.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, I think you could use `LOAD DATA INFILE` to load the files into a temp table, then use a cursor to iterate through the temp table and use `PREPARE` and `EXECUTE` to execute each one -- if MySQL allows those commands in a stored procedure -- but that's a really bad way of accomplishing this.  Stored procedures should be used for manipulating data in the DB, and `LOAD DATA INFILE` should be used to load data, not executable statements.  If you need to execute SQL that has been saved externally, you should use the [intended external methods](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-batch-commands.html) for doing so.

The reason you're having trouble finding out how to do what you're describing is because there's a much easier way to do what you're trying to accomplish, and what you're trying to do is against philosophy.

You can either create a batch or shell script file like so:

```
mysql db_name < FirstFile.sql
mysql db_name < SecondFile.sql
.
.
.
```

Or, you can create a master .sql file that sources the individual commands in order.  Say you have a file `master.sql` with contents like:

```
source FirstFile.sql
source SecondFile.sql
.
.
.
```

Then you run `mysql db_name < master.sql`.